# Gradle and Errors that appears after changes

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

Recently I tried to integrate firebase to my first project in android studio and the things who use to work in my project, suddenly don't.

The error that I'm getting is in the PlaceFragment (to search places ) where after done the changes starts to make me impossible to compile.

please, help me... I'm lost.

my build.gradle file is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}



android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "snowf.app.celiguide"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    dexOptions
            {
                incremental false
                javaMaxHeapSize "4048M"
                preDexLibraries = false
            }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.9'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.2.3'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'
    compile 'com.github.jrvansuita:PickImage:2.1.9'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.1.0'
    //  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    annotationProcessor 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.4'
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.4'
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    compile 'com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.7.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
    compile 'com.github.jaredrummler:Material-Spinner:1.0.8'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The error that I get is "error: cannot find symbol class id".

Thanks in advance.

Roman

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean/25706217), the error means that *either* there is a problem in your Java source code, or there is a problem in the way that you are compiling it. Also from this [page](http://net-informations.com/java/cjava/symbol.htm):

> The general causes for a `Cannot find symbol` error are things like:
>
> - Incorrect spelling.
> - Wrong case. Halo is different from halo.
> - Improper use of acceptable identifier values (letters, numbers, underscore, dollar sign), my-class is not the same as myclass.
> - No variable declaration or variable is outside of the scope you are referencing it in.

Comment: please can you suggest me where to start to search for that error? is my first time with android and i dont know where to start. thanks

Comment: Solved! the reason was the different version in google-play implementations in gradle. when i set the same version number the problem dissapears

Answer (score 0):

Solved! the reason was the different version in google-play implementations in gradle. when i set the same version number the problem dissapears